# larvael package that I develop throw: Uncaught Error: Class 'Dizaji\ToDo\Tests\TestCase' not found

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, package, phpunit

I develop my own package and for test I get this test:

> Uncaught Error: Class 'Dizaji\ToDo\Tests\TestCase' not found in
> C:\Users\A.Dizaji\PhpstormProjects\TddInLaravelPackage\packages\Dizaji\ToDo\tests\Unit
> \TaskTest.php:9

My struct is like this:

[image]

In phpunit.xml I change the code like this:

```
<testsuite name="Unit">
    <directory suffix="Test.php">packages\Dizaji\ToDo</directory>
</testsuite>
```

My TestCase in package is:

```
<?php

namespace Dizaji\ToDo\Tests;

use Dizaji\ToDo\ToDoServiceProvider;

class TestCase extends \Orchestra\Testbench\TestCase
{
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        // additional setup
    }

    protected function getPackageProviders($app)
    {
        return [
            ToDoServiceProvider::class,
        ];
    }

    protected function getEnvironmentSetUp($app)
    {
        // perform environment setup
    }}
```

and finally my test is:

```
<?php
namespace Dizaji\ToDo\Tests;
use Dizaji\ToDo\Tests\TestCase;
use Dizaji\ToDo\Task;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
//use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Webmozart\Assert\Assert;

class TaskTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    /** @test */
    function a_task_should_create_correct()
    {
        $task = Task::factory()->create(['title' => 'Fake Title','description'=>'fake description','status'=>1,'user_id'=>1]);
        Assert::true(true);
    }
}
```

Edit:And my composer.json in root is:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Dizaji\\ToDo\\": "packages/Dizaji/ToDo/src"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Dizaji\\ToDo\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
```

Comment: It’s the wrong TestCase class you are using

Comment: I can got it from errorCode but I don't know why its wrong. I do everything correct

Comment: It's not everything correct. Per PSR-4 `tests !== Tests`.

Comment: No you don’t do everything correct. Use Tests/TestCase

Comment: I did the answer of @Savlon but again error said that Test/TestCase not found. I think because that I write test in package so something should be different

Comment: I can't understand answer of @Tpojka .what i should I do and in where?

Comment: How have you defined your root namespace in your composer.json and are you initialising the composer autoloader in your tests (as in [this line of code](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/9.x/phpunit.xml#L4))

Comment: Your folder `tests` is in lowercase and needs to be `Tests`

Comment: @apokryfos I edit question and ass you can see I have composer.json like that.

Comment: you have `Dizaji\\ToDo` in `packages/Dizaji/ToDo/src` and `Dizaji\\ToDo\\Tests` in `tests/` but according to your screenshot it should probably be `packages/Dizaji/ToDo/tests/` (though it does seem like an odd setup if you're currently developing this package)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrong autoload path for your tests.

```
"Dizaji\\ToDo\\Tests\\": "tests/"
```

Should be

```
"Dizaji\\ToDo\\Tests\\": "packages/Dizaji/ToDo/tests"
```